# Error with Regex matching method for pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Test-143'], ['Test-1435'], ['Test-123'],['Test-12']], columns = ['column1'])

df
     column1
0   Test-143
1   Test-1435
2   Test-123
3   Test-12
```

Now I want to extract the records which have three digits with `Test-`. These records are `Test-143,Test-123`. when I tried to achieve it I am facing a few problems when I use regex patterns such as `Test-\d\d,Test-\d{3}` it gives me all records and when I restricted by placing `+$` its throwing me an error which is as follows:-

```
res = df[df['column1'].str.match(re.compile(r'Test-\d{3}+$'),na=False)]
res
error: multiple repeat at position 10
```

What does the error mean? How do I get the excepted output:-

```
     column1
0   Test-143
2   Test-123
```

Comment: The range `{3}` is a self contained quantifier. In Python only the `?` can pile-on to a quantifier, where `?` is reluctant. The `+` cannot be piled-on in Python re engine (in regex engine it can be). That pile-on with a plus `+` is a PCRE / Perl (or Python regex engine) construct meaning to be possessive, not give any back to backtracking (if it is so possible to backtrack). It is shorthand for atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are double-qualifying the amount of digits:

```
`\d{3}+$`
```

`\d{3}` means 3 digits AND `+` means 1 or more of the thing directly before the `+` - `$` is end of string.

Hence:

```
error: multiple repeat at position 10
```

Remove either one - if you want 3 digits remove the `+`.